# Webgl - adding DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer prevents rendering to cubemap framebuffer

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

We're working in Webgl 1 and attempting to render to a cubemap using a stencil. Rendering to the cubemap on its own works fine. When we add a `DEPTH_STENCIL` renderbuffer it stops writing to the cubemap and issues no error.

- This doesn't happen with a normal `TEXTURE_2D` instead of a `TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`.
- Depth/stencil/scissor tests are disabled.
- The call to `framebufferRenderbuffer` is what breaks it.
- Switching the renderbuffer to be either just a stencil or just a depth has the same effect.
- Switching the renderbuffer to be a colour buffer makes it work again.

Here's a minimal-ish recreation. As you can see, we're getting a console output with the correct values for the first three calls and zeroes for the last call.

Why is this happening and what little thing are we missing to make renderbuffers work with cubemaps?

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

console.log(TEST(false, false));
console.log(TEST(false, true));
console.log(TEST(true, false));
console.log(TEST(true, true));

function TEST(useCubemap, useBuffer) {
  const size = 512;
  const textureType = useCubemap ? gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP : gl.TEXTURE_2D;

  // SETUP THE PROGRAM
  {
    const program = gl.createProgram();
    const vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    const fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.shaderSource(vertShader, `
            attribute vec2 a_position;
            
            void main() {           
                gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0.2, 1.0);
            }
        `);
    gl.compileShader(vertShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, vertShader);

    gl.shaderSource(fragShader, `
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4);
            }
        `);
    gl.compileShader(fragShader);
    gl.attachShader(program, fragShader);

    gl.linkProgram(program);
    gl.useProgram(program);
  }

  // SETUP THE QUAD
  {
    const posBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1, +1, -1, -1, +1, +1, +1, -1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }

  // SETUP THE FRAMEBUFFER
  {
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

    gl.bindTexture(textureType, targetTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // SWITCH TEXTURE TYPE
    if (textureType === gl.TEXTURE_2D) {
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
      gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
      gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, targetTexture, 0);
    }
  }

  // SETUP THE RENDER BUFFER
  {
    const rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();

    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
    gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL, size, size);

    // TAKING THIS OUT MAKES IT WORK
    if (useBuffer) gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
  }


  // DISABLE THE OBVIOUS CULPRITS
  gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
  gl.disable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

  // DO A RENDERYFUCK
  gl.viewport(0, 0, size, size);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

  // GET THE OUTFUCK
  const pixels = new Uint8Array(4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
  return pixels;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. I get the same values for all 4 calls in the code you posted. What OS/GPU/Driver are you using? Can you pastebin your `about:gpu` contents if you're using Chrome?

It sounds like a bug in your drivers. It's possible it's a also a bug in the WebGL spec.

The OpenGL ES spec does **not** require any combinations of framebuffer attachments to work (zero, zilch, nada). The WebGL spec require 3 combinations to work. From [the spec, section 6.8](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#6.8):

> The following combinations of framebuffer object attachments, when all of the attachments are framebuffer attachment complete, non-zero, and have the same width and height, must result in the framebuffer being framebuffer complete:
>
> - COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture
> - COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_COMPONENT16 renderbuffer
> - COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 = RGBA/UNSIGNED_BYTE texture + DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT = DEPTH_STENCIL renderbuffer

But looking at the WebGL Conformance tests [only `TEXTURE_2D` is tested](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/renderbuffers/framebuffer-object-attachment.html).

So, first off that suggests your driver/gpu doesn't support that combination with cubemaps. Test by calling `gl.checkFramebufferStatus`. If it doesn't return `gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` your setup doesn't support rendering to a cubemap with a depth stencil attachment.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

TEST("TEXTURE_2D", "DEPTH_COMPONENT16");
TEST("TEXTURE_2D", "DEPTH_STENCIL");
TEST("TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP", "DEPTH_COMPONENT16");
TEST("TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP", "DEPTH_STENCIL");

function TEST(target, depthBufferFormat) {
  const size = 16;
  const textureType = gl[target];

  // SETUP THE FRAMEBUFFER
  {
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    const targetTexture = gl.createTexture();

    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

    gl.bindTexture(textureType, targetTexture);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(textureType, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // SWITCH TEXTURE TYPE
    if (textureType === gl.TEXTURE_2D) {
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
      gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, targetTexture, 0);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, gl.RGBA, size, size, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
      gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, targetTexture, 0);
    }
  }

  // SETUP THE RENDER BUFFER
  {
    const rb = gl.createRenderbuffer();
    const format = gl[depthBufferFormat];

    gl.bindRenderbuffer(gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
    gl.renderbufferStorage(gl.RENDERBUFFER, format, size, size);

    // TAKING THIS OUT MAKES IT WORK
    const attachmentPoint = depthBufferFormat === "DEPTH_COMPONENT16"
      ? gl.DEPTH_ATTACHMENT
      : gl.DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT;
    gl.framebufferRenderbuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, attachmentPoint, gl.RENDERBUFFER, rb);
  }

  const success =  gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) === gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE;
  console.log(target, depthBufferFormat, success ? "PASS" : "**FAIL**");
}
```

Do you need the stencil or just the depth buffer? Does [this sample run](http://webglsamples.org/dynamic-cubemap/dynamic-cubemap.html) for you? It's using a `DEPTH_COMPONENT16` attachment.

Comment: Ugh, we were slightly starting to fear a driver-bug, thanks. We're running VMWare's emulated GPU driver, which is theoretically OpenGL3.3 capable, but perhaps more buggy than most. We've already hit a bug where it's not supporting Webgl2 when we think it should, that's been filed with Chromium at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=864014.

`gl.checkFramebufferStatus` returns `gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` in all cases, nothing indicates any kind of error. Switching to `DEPTH_COMPONENT16` makes no difference. The sample you linked runs without error, but the ball is solid blue.

Comment: Oh, and the sample you linked, sometimes loads with a background? Looks like it's only loading one face of the cubemap and there's some flickering on the screen that looks like it might be the cubemap-image being occasionally drawn to the screen-buffer in the lower left. Yeah, that seems like a driver-bug, huh.

Comment: Don't want to push our luck on this question, might ask this as a separate Q, but do you happen to have an idea for another way to achieve our aim? We're trying to slowly update an expensive dynamic skybox over multiple frames and only update every fourth pixel per frame. We were going to do that with a stencil. Currently planning to try to emulate a cubemap with a `TEXTURE_2D` and custom sampling logic in the shader, but if you happen to know a better direction to point us in that would be appreciated as that's a mess near edges.

Comment: Yes you should probably open a new question but ... have you tested that using a stencil to update every 4th pixel actually saves enough time? You could do that testing in 2D rather than a cube map

Comment: Actually meant every fourth in each dimension, so every 16th per frame. Assuming early stencil-testing can chuck them out it should be plenty as it runs about 20ms on its own, but no we've not tested yet, we got sidetracked by this. We're (roughly) working to the spec of the famous Horizon Zero Dawn clouds paper though, the update-every-16th trick is lifted from there, though they don't specify the method. We'll investigate getting the driver fixed (probably unlikely) and other ways to achieve that effect and then ask another question if we're still stuck.

Comment: Are they showing the cube map at all times or are they double buffering and every 16 frames switching to the newly generating cubemap? If they're double buffering then no need for a stencil, just set the viewport or 1/4 of the face of a cubemap. Either a vertical or horizontal slice. You can generate the correct projection map using the `frustum` function in most 3d math libs.

Comment: They're not using a cubemap at all as far as I know, they're drawing to the screen and using reprojection to update only 1/16th of the cloud-pixels per frame. We need a full cubemap for reflection, so we're planning on doing 1/16th of a face per frame, such that the full update happens over 80 frames (no ground). The sky changes very slowly so this should be fine, but we think (no, not tested yet) that swapping out every 80 frames / 1.3 seconds will cause a slight visible jump. Updating one face at a time will likely cause a slight seam.

Comment: We're also considering double buffering and swapping which buffer we sample from according to where we are in the update-cycle. This would probably work for our specular, but we were going to be doing diffuse lobe samples too. We could do a separate lower-res skybox or something for that, but it's a mess.